# Is it possible to install Phoenix OS on a 64 bit computer?

Tags: android, phoenix

I want to run the android os Phoenix on my PC, but it is 64 bit. Is it possible to install on a 64 bit pc?

Comment: *"my PC ... is 64 bit"* -- No, your PC is not likely to have a CPU that is restricted to 64-bit operation. Intel x86-64 processors have both 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

Comment: And PhoenixOS has a 64-bit version.

Comment: I wasn’t able to find one specifically for 64 bit.